# how to send selected checkbox values over multiple pages using pagination

Tags: java, grails, pagination, session-variables

I have a checkboxlist in my form as following, the list of checkboxes is dynamic using a list of documents from database  , these documents could be from 100 to 10000 so i use the pagination to send max and offset to my controller here is the code :

```
<tbody>
    <g:each var="invoice" in="${documentListbyAll}">
        <tr onclick="selectRow(this)">
            <td>${document.id}</td>
            <td>${document.name}</td>
            <td>${document.Type.nameType}</td>
            <td class="center">${document.Status}</td>
            <td class="center">${document.Date}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="document" value="${document.id}" name="document">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<g:paginate controller="displayDocument" action="index" total="${documentListCount}" max="10" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>treat</button>
```

this code shows a table containing a **list of documents** and i have the **pagination** , the problem is : the user has to select some documents from different pages , but the pagination loads the pages => i can't save the documents selected in previous pages

i am thinking of using a session variable but i don't know how , If anyone could give me any help or point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.